# Is there a way to indicate that a string model property has a maximum length in Swagger?

Tags: java, rest, swagger

### Context

We have a web application providing multiple REST webservice.

Along with this, we have swagger providing the documentation for the resources, using annotation.

Some of these resources take a complex object in input as a body param. The class of this object is annotated with `@ApiModel`.

In some cases, we limit the length of some string properties, using `@Length` annotation from Bean Validations.

### Question

We want to see these restrictions to be visible in the documentation generated by swagger. Is there a way to do this?

P.S.: the automatic interpretation of the `@Length` annotation would be nice but is not mandatory. Any other way would work too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do very nicely if you are using spring project and you are using spring fox swagger api.
Consider a bean -

```
public class Person {
    @NotNull
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp ="[SOME REGULAR EXPRESSION]")
    private String lastName;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(100)
    private int age;

    //... Constructor, getters, setters, ...
}
```

Use Maven dependency -

```
//MAVEN
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
//MAVEN
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This will do your magic - @Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
And you need to import BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration configuration file on top of your swagger configuration class:

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    @Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
    public class SpringFoxConfig {
      ...
    }
```

If you dont have a configuration class for swagger then put it above your controller

```
 @RestController
     @EnableSwagger2
        @Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
    @RequestMapping("/v2/persons/")
    @Api(description = "Set of endpoints for Creating, Retrieving, Updating and Deleting of Persons.")
    public class PersonController {

        private PersonService personService;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        @ApiOperation("Returns list of all Persons in the system.")
        public List getAllPersons() {
            return personService.getAllPersons();
        }
```

With data from JSR-303 annotations, it will look much better in swagger documentation:

```
{
        age integer ($int32)
                    minimum: 100
                    maximum: 100
        firstName* string
                minimumLength: 100
                maxLength: 100
    }
```

JSR 303: Bean Validation allows you to annotate fields of your Java classes to declare constraints and validation rules. You can annotate individual fields with rules such as -- cannot be null, minimal value, maximal value, regular expression match and so on.
This is a common practice which is already widely used. The good news is that SpringFox can generate Swagger documentation based on such annotations, so you can utilize what you already have in your project without writing all the constraints manually! It is very useful as consumers of your API know what are restrictions on the values they should provide to your API and what values to expect. Without the inclusion of such annotations, the generated documentation for our person model looks rather plain, nothing except for field names and their data type.

Answer (score 10):

Using the `@ApiModelProperty` Swagger annotation, you can use `dataType`, `allowableValues` and `range`:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Nome da lista", required = false, 
    dataType="java.lang.String", 
    allowableValues="range[-infinity, 100]")
String getNome();
```

Result on Swagger UI:

[image]

The `-infinity` is used to hide the minimum value. If you would like to set the min value, just fill with the number:

```
allowableValues="range[5, 100]"
```

Comment: This is the answer. THX!  Use allowableValues you can see the length restriction  in the documentation generated by swagger.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, see [this section](http://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject) of the swagger spec. You can specify a `maxLength` or `minLength` for your property. Here is an example in YAML:

```
definitions:
  Error:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
        maxLength: 20
```

This would be displayed by swagger-ui like this:

[image]

Comment: is there a way of doing this using swagger annotations?

Comment: I don't use annotations, but assuming you use Java you could try to set an hibernate.validator of type Length or Range...

Comment: Yes, but how to do it using annotations..

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using Springdoc, this can be achieved using the `@Schema` annotation.

`@Schema(maxLength = 192) private String value;`

This will output a
[maxLength property on the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3KOw.png)

Comment: Please don't post code images or bugs if possible, copy your code or code error into answer with block code format. Please take the tour and read How to Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer